# What happens when the length of the uniform wire is more than or less than 54 cm?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

I understand how to solve this (when $V_{BC}$ is equal to the emf of the second cell then the current through the second cell is zero). However, I'm curious what happens when the length BC is more than or less than 54 cm? Would current flow through the branch? In what direction?

> In the *potentiometer* in Figure 5.32 wire AB is uniform and has a
> length of 1.00 m. When contact is made at C with BC = 54.0 cm, the
> galvanometer G shows zero current. What is the emf of the second cell?
>
> [image]

Comment: If you understand how to solve the problem, then you should do the math for those different lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The two loop equations (neglect the resistance of galvanometer):
$$
i_1 R_1 + (i_1 + i_2) R_2 = 120; \\
(i_1 + i_2) R2 = 120*0.54 = 64.8   \tag{1}
$$
Where the resistance $R_1$ and $R_2$ is proportional to the length:
$$
   R_1 = R (1-x); \text{  and  } R_2 = R x \tag{2}
$$
Where $R$ is the total resistance os the bar, and $x$ (in meters) is the length for $R_2$ of the smaller loop.

Substitute Eq.(2) into Eq.(1)

$$
   i_1 R (1-x) = 120 - 64.8 = 55.2 \\
   i_1 R x + i_2 R_2 = 64.8            \tag{3}
$$

Replace $i_1 R$ in Eq.3(b) from Eq.3(a)
$$
  i_2 R_2 = 64.8 - 55.2 \frac{x}{1-x}. 
$$

If $i_2 R_2 \gt 0$ then the direction of $i_2$ is clockwise as what is shown in the above figure, else for $i_2 R_2 \lt 0$, $i_2$ is in counter-clockwise, opposite to the direction in the figure.

The following Graph shows the magnitude of $i_2 R_2$ as function of $x$, for $x < 0.54$ the $i_2$ is in clockwise, and $x > 0.54$, $i_2$ in counter-clockwise direction.
[image]